# Flip orientation of Font Markers on line when upside down using QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression

I would like to have font markers flip when they are upside down but otherwise follow the line angle.
Here is an image of how they look now:

[image: font markers 'AB' on upper line are upside down]

I would like them to look like this:

[image: font markers on both lines are not upside down]

I achieved this by switching the line direction but I want to do it through the style and I would like to do it at the marker level not the line level.
I have tried a geometry generator to switch the line.

`if(y_max( $geometry)>y_min($geometry),$geometry,reverse($geometry))`

But this only switches the issue to the bottom line.

[image: font marker on bottom line is upside down]

I also tried a data defined override on the font marker rotation with these expressions.

```
if( @symbol_angle < 180,0,180)
if(y_max( $geometry)<  y_min($geometry),0,180)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of font-markers do you have: is there a separate point-layer thay is styled with font-markers? Are do they represent a label? How did you create the font-arkers?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. QGIS has no way of getting the location of a marker. What about using a repeating label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with "font markers" for your text, set the following for data defined override of the rotation:

```
if(line_interpolate_angle($geometry,0)>180,180,0)
```

This checks, whether the line is "flipped" and if it is, tells the symbology to rotate the text by 180 degrees, otherwise it stays, as it is.

I did some additional testing, and this solution does not take changes of line direction into account.

Comment: @Baswein I did some additional testing, and this solution does not take changes of line direction into account, it solely cares about the start direction/orientation of the line.

Comment: Yes I see that. Maybe not perfect ;).  But way better than before! I tried this but it didn't work. if(line_interpolate_angle( segments_to_lines( $geometry),0)>180,180,0)

Comment: You probably could make up something with the current label location and `angle at vertex` for the closest vertex of the line - still, it is rather complicated, I think @Baswein